# How to Make Tkinter Always On Top of Windows Taskbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a customized clock with TK(), and I wanted to cover it over the default Windows clock on the taskbar.

I tried setting tk.attributes('-topmost', True), but it is only above other windows but not the task bar.

How may I make TK stay on top of the task bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you TK stay on top of the task bar:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-tkinter-window-appear-in-the-taskbar

Comment: No, this only adds an image icon in the taskbar. It is not what the question is about, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).